# Pass the location of file in python script call instead of variable

Tags: python

```
    os.system('script2.py -path location -format csv')
```

I am calling the above script with arguments as mentioned above from another python script `script1.py`. I have the variable "`location`" with the value `/tmp/user1/file.csv`
I should have the location replaced with this path `/tmp/user1/file.csv` since the switch `-input_path` takes only file location as argument value.

I also used

`cmd = 'script2.py -path location -format csv'`

`subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)`

but did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass cmd as an array also.

Try using

```
cmd = ["script2.py", "-path", location, "-format", "csv"]

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you just want to replace 'location' with your variable location? If that is the case you can use an f string (or other equivalent if you are not running python 3.6+)

```
os.system(f'script2.py -path {location} -format csv'
```

Does that help? Sorry if I misunderstood the question

Comment: I am using python 2.7. the f string did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I wanted to replace location with the path of file.

Comment: I've never really used python 2.x but I think this would work: `os.system('script2.py -path %s -format csv' % location)`